# create List of List and read excel File

Tags: c#, excel, model-view-controller

I would like to read an excel file with exceldatareader but I don't know how many cells my excel file has. So I've created a list class but I don't know if I'm doing the right thing.

```
public class TESIView
        {
            public class Information
            {
                public List<RowObject> Riga { get; set; }
            }
            public class RowObject
            {
                public List<CellObject> Cella { get; set; }
            }
            public class CellObject
            {
                public string Valore { get; set; }
            }
        }
```

and i have a this controller:

```
public string TESIVisualizza(string filename, string hostname, string location)
        {
            Models.TESIView.Information TesiInformation = new Models.TESIView.Information
            {
                Riga = new List<Models.TESIView.RowObject>()
            };

            using (var stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/File/" + filename), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        TesiInformation.Riga.Add(new Models.TESIView.RowObject()
                        {
                            Cella = Cell.Add(new Models.TESIView.CellObject()
                            {
                                Valore = reader.GetValue(1).ToString()
                            })
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TesiInformation);
        }
```

I tried different solutions but I don't know what to put inside Riga.add. In the example, I put the reader.getValue(1) but I always get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Without additional code and a clear definition of the error you are getting, it will be difficult to decipher, what could be wrong. I am not that familiar with `ExcelDataReader`, however, from the first sentence in your question…

> *”… but I don't know how many cells my excel file has.”* …

I am pretty sure there is an easier way than reading the Excel file row by row.

With a little research and from my understanding using the … [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/blob/develop/README.md) … library, there is an additional library you can install called `ExcelDataReader.DataSet`. With it, you can use something like…

```
DataSet result;

using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
  using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream)) {
    result = reader.AsDataSet();
  }
}
```

This will fill the `DataSet` such that each `Worksheet` in the `Workbook` will be a `DataTable` in the `DataSet’s` collection of `DataTables`. Example, `result.Tables[0]` would be the `workbooks` first `worksheet` etc.… I am guessing this may be easier that using a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

I mis-explained what I wanted to do. I wanted to find an easy way to be able to interact with the columns that interested me. For example now I am interested in columns 1,3,4, but one day I might be interested in columns 1,2,5.
I found a solution that works for me but I don't like it so much that I have to use a double replace for the square brackets

```
DataSet result;

using (var stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/File/" + filename), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    List<int> Colonne = new List<int> { 0, 2 };
    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
    {
        result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
        {
            ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
            {
                FilterColumn = (rowReader, columnIndex) =>
                {
                    return Colonne.Contains(columnIndex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

ArrayList root = new ArrayList();
List<Dictionary<string, object>> table;
Dictionary<string, object> data;

foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
{
    table = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            data.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        table.Add(data);
    }
    root.Add(table);
}


return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Misura = root }).Replace("[[","[").Replace("]]", "]");
```